# problem with synchronized method in java

Tags: java, database, multithreading, synchronized

I have following implementation in Java where I am trying to use a synchronized method:

```
class dbAccess{  
     public synchronized void getGUID(){  
           counter=/*Access last count from txn_counter table */
           /*Insert a unique value to txn_counter table based on the acquired value of counter */ 
           /*Insert new counter value to GUID_log table */
     }  
}
```

The portion between /* */ represent some sql queries. The implementation has 10 threads. I was hoping that counter value returned everytime would be unique. But it so happens that multiple runs return same value of counter.

Can you please point out if I am doing anything wrong. And, is it the right way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Just because it is synchronised in java, does not mean it is synchronised on the database. This method needs to run in a database transaction with read locking enabled.

Comment: The most important part of running in a transaction is that the changed value in txn_counter needs to be committed to the database before the next thread reads the "last count from txn_count".

Comment: This is sound advice, but if the database is dedicated to the application and there is only one instance of the application and he is in fact committing those changes in the db code, then synchronizing way up in the application would work. Though obviously it would be rather fragile based on those preconditions that have to be met.

Comment: @Tim, my db and application meet the situation you describe. The db is dedicated to application and there is only one instance of application running. And, I have been trying to synchronize the database access part from application. I hoped it would acquire locks while reading and writing to database.

Comment: For it to behave as you expect though you're going to need to transaction boundary to be the same as this synchronized boundary.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you have several instances of `dbAccess`? (The `synchronized` keyword works on object level not on class level.) In that case you need to make the method static (may not be feasible in your situation), or try to have a static lock protecting the method body, like this:

```
class dbAccess{  
    private final static Object o = new Object();

    public void getGUID(){  
        synchronized (o) {
            counter=/*Access last count from txn_counter table */
            // Insert a unique value to txn_counter table based on
            // the acquired value of counter
            // Insert new counter value to GUID_log table
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problem of multiple instances of dbAccess. This was what I was doing. Now, I am trying to implement it as static method as you suggest. I hope this works for me.